# hibernate OneToOne NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, wildfly-11

i have this code

```
private PostsContentsEntity contentsEntity;

@OneToOne( targetEntity = PostsContentsEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "PostId",referencedColumnName = "PostId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public PostsContentsEntity getContentsEntity() {
    return this.contentsEntity;
}

public void setContentsEntity(PostsContentsEntity contentsEntity) {
    this.contentsEntity = contentsEntity;
}
```

on database 
post table

```
PostId  UserId  PostTime
7   3   2018-02-27 02:52:21
8   3   2018-02-27 02:52:38
9   3   2018-02-27 02:52:57
10  3   2018-02-27 02:53:52
11  3   2018-02-27 02:54:01
```

post content table

```
PostContentId   PostId  Content MediaUrl    ContentType
1   7   text post   noMedia 1
2   8   photo post  image/TueFeb27025238MST2018_1519725158056.jpg   2
3   9   video post  video/TueFeb27025257MST2018_1519725177971.mp4   3
4   10  text post   noMedia 1
5   11  photo post  image/TueFeb27025401MST2018_1519725241249.jpg   2
```

the problem is 
when the `PostId` on `post table` =  `PostContentId` on `post content table` it's return successfully data
but if it's not equal `PostContentId` return `NullPointerException`

i added `@JoinColumn(name = "PostId",referencedColumnName = "PostId")` to join with `PostId` not `PostContentId` but same problem !!

Comment: Your title says `ManyToOne` but in your code theres only a `OneToOne`-Annotation. Is this your code that throws the exception or just an example?

Comment: yes it on OneToOne not ManyToOne

Comment: Can you post the whole code for both `entities`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the relation between your entities is not correctly mapped.

Let my copy this sample code from [Oracle Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)

*Example 1: One-to-one association that maps a foreign key column*

```
// On Customer class:

@OneToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(
    name="CUSTREC_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
public CustomerRecord getCustomerRecord() { return customerRecord; }

// On CustomerRecord class:

@OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="customerRecord")
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

As you can see usually the annotation `@JoinColumn` is placed in the entity that represents the table that got the **FOREIGN_KEY**. In your case, the foreign key seems to be placed in POST_CONTENT pointing to POST.

You have to place `@JoinColumn` in your class `PostsContentsEntity`. 
Following the example, `PostsEntity` should have an object mapped with a property in `PostsContentsEntity`

Something like this

```
// On PostsContentsEntity class:

@OneToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(
    name="POST_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
public PostsEntity getPostsEntity() { return postsEntity; }

// On PostsEntity class:

@OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="postsEntity")
public PostsContentsEntity getPostsContentsEntity() { return postsContentsEntity; }
```